# Attachement not getting attached in android while sending mail

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application which sends a .csv file as attachement, i have given permsissions in the manifest and reffered to lot of codes but everytime when i send an attachement, the mail comes without the attachement. I have referred to many stackoverflow solutions but they do not have effect at all.

here is the code.

```
sendmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 sendEmail();
            }

             protected void sendEmail() {
      Log.i("Send email", "");

      String TO = email.getText().toString();

      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

      emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{TO});
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("excerDB.csv"));
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your ward's academic details are here");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find the details attached....");
      startActivity(emailIntent);
      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(DisplayContact.this, 
         "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
        });
```

P.S :- i tried it running on gennymotion emulator and on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

> Attachement not getting attached in android while sending mail

Becuase you are not passing right path of `csv` file to `Uri.parse`.

To create valid `URI` you should provide complete path of file :

```
Uri uriFile=Uri.parse(<File_Location_On_Int./Ext. Sd_Card>+"/excerDB.csv");
```

Now use `uriFile` as `EXTRA_STREAM` key value.

Comment: i did as you have told, the file is getting attached in gmail and i can see the attached file but the recipient is not getting the file emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      Uri uriFile=Uri.parse("excerDB.csv");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{TO});
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriFile);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your ward's academic details are here");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find the details attached....");
      startActivity(emailIntent);

Comment: @sleeper: where is `excerDB.csv` file located on device ?

Comment: @sleeper: if file is at `/sdcard/` then pass full path as `Uri uriFile=Uri.parse("/sdcard/excerDB.csv");`

Comment: Sorry bro, i tried even that, the file is getting attached in the email client but after sending it is not getting delivered to reciepient.

Comment: @sleeper: `i did as you have told, the file is getting attached in gmail and i can see the attached file` when you are passing wrong path for file in `Uri.parse` then how file is attached and you are able to see? .  check logcat response i'm  email application will show some error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69710/discussion-between-sleeper-and--k).

Comment: E/Email(2255): Failed to cache attachment {
: E/Email(2255):     "flags": 0,E/Email(2255):     "contentUri": "\/sdcard\/excerDB.csv",
 E/Email(2255):     "thumbnailUri": "\/sdcard\/excerDB.csv",
 E/Email(2255):     "_display_name": "excerDB.csv",
 E/Email(2255):     "state": 0,
E/Email(2255):     "supportsDownloadAgain": false,
 E/Email(2255):     "_size": 0,
E/Email(2255):     "contentType": "",
01-28 05:25:58.816: E/Email(2255):     "type": 0,
01-28 05:25:58.816: E/Email(2255):     "providerData": "",
E/Email(2255):     "downloadedSize": 0,
 E/Email(2255):     "destination": 0

Comment: @sleeper: ok try to pass an image from drawable as `    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ "/drawable/" + R.drawable.any_image_name_from_drawable);` and let me know user is getting image in attachment ?

Comment: THE gmail application crashed a lot of times, but it sent the image just once.

Answer (score 0):

You EXTRA_STREAM variable is wrong :

try below :

Open a gallery to choose file from button click :

```
 public void openGallery() {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setType("image/*");
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
              startActivityForResult(
                           Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                           PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

       }
```

On Activity Result save the URI ;

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 /**
                  * Get Path, chnage type accordingly
                  */
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                 String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();
                 columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                 attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
                 URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
                 cursor.close();
          }
   }
```